# Calculate value from an equation using Field Calculator Python/VB Script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, vbscript

I wanted to calculate a result value from 3 fields using an equation.

VBScript or Python codes are also accepted..:-)

[image]

the equation is RESULT= [(R^2/3)(S^1/2)]/n..

Comment: is that R to the power of 2 divided by 3?? Not sure what the ^ operator is here.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to show what you have already tried in the Field Calculator, please?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: Yes, it is exponential form..

Comment: @PolyGeo: i have not tried anything yet because it looks like python/vb script and I am a newbee in coding. I have search many sites and I think coding is really needed here to solve my problem. hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression looks incomplete but I am assuming that the first part of it is trying to find the square of the cube root.

My test below on that when R had a value of 8 returned the expected value of 4 to the RESULT field

RESULT =

```
[R] ^ ( 2 / 3 )
```

The above worked when the parser is set to VBScript.

With Python, there is hopefully an easier way but I got it to work with:

RESULT =

```
math.pow(!R!,( float(2) / float(3) ))
```

My testing used ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop on a file geodatabase feature class.

Perhaps your whole expression in VBScript is:

```
([R]^(2/3))*([S]^(1/2))/[n]
```

Comment: thanks a lot..u really help me solve my problem..till next time..:-)